# Check null value of a field result query Linq to Entity

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-entities

See the select below.

```
dim query = from a in MyContext.MyTables
Where Not a.ID = 1
Select a
```

I want to check if a value of a field is null. I am doing the following:

```
if query.count > o then
    if a(0)("field") is nothing then
           messagebox.show("INVALID VALUE FOR RETURNING")
    end if
end if
```

It is generation an exepction that I can't compare the value a(0)("field").

How should I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: try `if a(0)("field").tostring = string.empty then`

Comment: Tks for the anwswer. But I keep having the same issue.